# SQL Syntax Error when using Group by conditional expression

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run SQL procedure with group by conditional expression

```sql
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        (WHEN tnx_order = TRUE THEN `txn`.id ASC) END,
        (WHEN tnx_order = FALSE THEN `txn`.id DESC) END
    LIMIT 1;
```

And i get this type of error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`` WHEN tnx_order = TRUE THEN `txn`.id ASC) END, ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your parenthesis are wrong. The wrapped construction is not single scalar expression.
2. You cannot use ASC/DESC modifier as a subpart of the expression.

If `txn.id` is numeric then use simple

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN tnx_order 
         THEN txn.id 
         ELSE -txn.id 
         END 
    LIMIT 1;
```

If it is not numeric then use

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN tnx_order
         THEN txn.id 
         ELSE 0
         END,
    CASE WHEN tnx_order
         THEN 0 
         ELSE txn.id
         END DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

PS. `tnx_order` is boolean, hence additional comparing it with TRUE or FALSE makes no sense. It can be used as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `tnx_order` coming from? You have additional parenthesise and you can’t return `asc` or `desc` within the case statement.

You might want

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN tnx_order THEN txn.id ELSE NULL END ASC
, CASE WHEN !tnx_order THEN txn.id ElSE NULL END DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If `tnx_order` is a variable then you’d probably be better off having two different queries with the alternate `order by` clauses and have your application decide which to run. This would better take advantage of indexes to provide no sort plans.

Comment: `tnx_order` its boolean parameter which im passing to procedure. So in general if tnx_order is true, then i need to sort column called txn.id in ascending order. Else in descending

Comment: Then you want two sql statements with an `if` condition in your procedure to decide which one gets executed

Answer (score 0):

You are in a stored procedure?  You have the tools there to "construct" the query.  Use the proc's `IF` statement or function to help you decide what to `CONCAT` together to make the query.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT( "SELECT ... ORDER BY id ",
                   IF(tnx_order, 'ASC', 'DESC') );
```

Then `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` `@sql`.

Easy, clear, and possibly generates a more efficient query.